# Active Rigid Body alembic sequence from RealFlow to Blender does not work

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation, alembic

I have a problem with making certain .abc sequence work in Blender.

Imported *Soft Body* .abc sequence from RealFlow to Blender works just fine.

Imported *Active Rigid Body* .abc sequence from RealFlow to Blender does nothing, object is just still.

When I import *Active Rigid Body* .abc files to Blender manually, I can see that they are each different, so the animation should theoretically work.

Can anyone help?

Files here (1 MB): https://wetransfer.com/downloads/65a896a9e0f421d45c9782d03eada46b20181027164434/edd6a4e2a3eac2eba8bd698faeeaf22920181027164434/bfbe0a

Answer (score 0):

In the RealFlow export settings for the rigid body check 'Export data' and 'Geometry(.obj)'

Install the Stop Motion add-on in Blender
https://github.com/neverhood311/Stop-motion-OBJ

Now you can import rigid bodies with the Mesh Sequence import option